# MySQL Combing Select from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, union

I'm trying to track sports stat data, I have two tables set up as follows (Teams will change based on the week):

Table 1:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
|  Team   |   PYardG    |   RYardG    |   TDG    |  
+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| Steelers  | 250       | 120         | 3  |  
| Broncos  | 200        | 130         | 2  |  
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Table 2:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
|  Week  |  Team1  |  Team2  |  Team3  |  
+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| Week1  | Steelers  | Broncos  | Colts  |  
| Week2  | Patriots  | Giants  | Cowboys  |  
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Ideally my output would look like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
|  Week1  |  PYardG  |  RYardG  |  TDG  |  
+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| Steelers  | 250    | 120      | 3  |  
| Broncos  | 200     | 130      | 2  |  
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The goal being to display the stats from Table 1, by Team based on the Week and Team name in Table 2.

In doing some research I can't figure out if a subquery, JOIN or UNION is my best bet. Is there a way to lookup the stats from Table 1 based on the team name and week in Table 2? I appreciate the help!

EDIT: I apologize for the poorly formatted tables, still brand new at this. 
Edit 2: Added desired output as well. Table 1 would change depending on the week, I've got a script to store the stats by week that I"m looking for.

Comment: It ia not clear what your desired output is.  Can you include actual data?

Comment: Your expected output differs from `Table1` only by the name of the first column.  Are you sure you have your data correct?

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be easier to have a table storing the stats and a separate table storing the teams by week rather than one giant table where I would have to store all of that.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you're trying to do. The output table doesn't have anything from Table 2 in it.

Comment: Do you mean that for the output table with the `Week1` column, it should only have rows for teams that are named in the `Week1` row of Table 2?

Comment: From Table 2, I want to display by week the teams that I've chosen but draw the individual stats for those teams from Table 1.

Comment: "Do you mean that for the output table with the Week1 column, it should only have rows for teams that are named in the Week1 row of Table 2?" - Exactly, with the stats of those teams from Table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` to get all the teams from `Table2` into a single column of a subquery. Then join that with `Table1`.

```
SELECT t1.team AS Week1, PYardG, RYardG, TDG
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT Team1 AS team FROM Table2
      WHERE week = 'Week1'
      UNION
      SELECT Team2 FROM Table2
      WHERE week = 'Week1'
      UNION
      SELECT Team3 FROM Table2
      WHERE week = 'Week1') AS t2
ON t1.team = t2.team
```

It would be easier if you normalized your data so that the teams are in separate rows in `Table2`, rather than multiple columns of the same row. Then you could simply join with the table instead of having to pivot the columns into rows of the subquery.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change the structure of table 2.
it can be like

```
+---------+---------+
|  Week  |  Team |  
+---------+---------+ 
| Week1  | Steelers  | 
| Week1  | Broncos  |
| Week1  | Colts   |
| Week2  | Patriots  | 
+---------+---------+
```

beacuse if there is more than three teams, then you need change the structure everytime, which is bad for data integrity.

then you can use simple select query to fetch the data.

select t1.Team, t1.PYardG,t1.RYardG,t1.TDG, t2.week  from table1 t1, table2 t2 where week = 'week1' and t1.team = t2.team;